# How to setup ODBC on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, unixodbc, mysql-odbc-connector

I am trying to setup ODBC for an old application, what use ODBC to connect MySQL DB.
Seem like have any tutorial to setup ODBC, or have but old OS version.
I tried to install UnixODBC by: `sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2 libodbc1 odbcinst unixodbc`.
And now I am trying to install MySQL ODBC. Have 3 method to install it.

1. Installing Connector/ODBC Using the MySQL Yum Repository
   (Yum cannot install on Ubuntu 20.04)
2. Installing Connector/ODBC from a Binary Tarball Distribution
   (Latest version seem like has not support)
3. Installing Connector/ODBC from a DEB Distribution
   I find the way to install a deb package file and try `sudo apt install mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.31-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb` but error `Unable to locate package mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.31-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`

I am stuck here. And have no way to reseach.
Could you help me!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-connector-odbc_8.0.31-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

`apt-get` will try to install it from your repos (and fail).  To make it install from your local copy of a .deb file, give it the full path to the .deb file (or prefix with `./` if it's in your current directory).